# Perl: GD:SecurityImage, angle property not working

Tags: perl, captcha

I am trying to create a Security Image from a text using the perl module GD:SecurityImage with the following object:

```
my $image = GD::SecurityImage->new(
              width   => 220,
              height  => 60,
              lines   => 5,
              scramble => 1,
              angle   => 45,
              gd_font => 'giant',
           );

$image->create( normal => 'circle' );
$image->particle(30, 70);
```

But the text in resulted image doesn't have the text angled at 45 Degrees rather its random.
Also if i make scramble = 0 and have angle = 45, the text doesn't rotate at that angle, text is just default in the image as seen [image]in the attach screen.

Please help me out, what am i doing wrong here?.

NOTE: Image is with scramble = 0;

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? I think your image does not look the way the code describes it. The text istn `scrambled` at all and I can't see the 5 `lines`. Font doesn't look like a `giant` either, though that is just a guess.

Comment: @simbabque : Font is giant, the image as i have said is with scramble =0. But as scramble is off and angle is set text didnt rotate to that angle.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. When I set `scramble` to 1 some of the letters are rotated 90 degrees regardless of the `angle` property. I'd say there's something broken here. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque for conforming. I also thought that something is broken, but thought of conforming it before i made my mind :)

Comment: Have you tried it with Image Magick? I can't test it right now, but maybe it works that way. Code looks like the actual text is created in the backend (makes sense somehow...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you must have Math::Trig to rotate with GD, otherwise you get no rotation. You don't need that with the ImageMagick backend - try that. (And use TTF :))